# Checking if bit is not set

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

If I use this:
`if(value & 4)` to check if the bit is set, then how do I check if the bit isn't set?

I tried with
`if(!value & 4)` or `if(~value & 4)` and `if(value ^ 4)` but none of them works.

Comment: How do you usually negate the value of a boolean expression?

Comment: kinda surprised `(~value & 4)` didn't work

Comment: Me either, I am looking for dependencies. If it is system-specific, inds-specific or method-specific..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

When you write `if(value & 4)`, C checks the result to be non-zero. Essentially, it means

```
if((value & 4) != 0) {
    ...
}
```

Therefore, if you would like to check that the bit is *not* set, compare the result for equality to zero:

```
if((value & 4) == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I will be more specific then. I have enumeration: http://hastebin.com/mipuwejufi.cpp and I am using the condition: http://hastebin.com/exaroviwov.mel to break out a loop. Thats the only condition in the loop, that increments and unfortunately - goes forever. Otherwise, if the bit is set the loop breaks successfully.

Comment: @Protogrammer There's a second condition there, are you sure that's not the culprit?

Comment: No, because the vlaue of `cur_w` increments freely and waits to be stopped.

Comment: @Protogrammer Did you try `if((cur_w > source.xpos + source.width) && (source.attributes & DBOX_HAS_SHADOW) == 0) { break; }`

Comment: @Protogrammer The `{ break; return; }` doesn't make sense... if this is in a loop, it'll break out of the loop but skip the `return;`

Comment: Yes and it didn't work. I don't think there is a huge matter though.

Comment: @Dmitri Yes, I know. I just want to be sure that the condition will be true no matter of the loop cycle.

Comment: @Protogrammer Are you sure the `DBOX_HAS_SHADOW` bit in the `source.attributes` is set to zero? If it is set to `1`, the loop needs to set it to zero, otherwise it would never finish.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight What do you mean set it to zero? I set it to `DBOX_HAS_BACKGROUND | DBOX_HAS_SHADOW`

Comment: @Protogrammer If you set the attribute to `DBOX_HAS_BACKGROUND | DBOX_HAS_SHADOW` and never change it, the condition `(source.attributes & DBOX_HAS_SHADOW) == 0` will always be `false`, so the overall condition will be `false` as well (because it's `&&`) so the code would never reach `break`,

Comment: Well then.. what am I supposed to do? If I "change it" how I will keep the setting.

Comment: @Protogrammer What "functionality" are you trying to keep? Your question describes a very specific scenario - checking a bit for zero. All three answers show how this can be done. There is no other functionality mentioned in your question. It sounds like the problem that you are trying to solve is different from the question that you asked. Consider asking a different, more specific question for that.

Comment: In the code I provided you with there is an enumeration with 4 options you can give to a function. These options are set with `option1 | option2..` The true checking is clear.. the false checking doesn't work. Thats all.

Answer (score 18):

You could do it many ways, but the easiest (easiest as in requires the least amount of thought) would be just negate the entire expression you already have:

```
if (!(value & 4))
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply:

```
if ((value & 4) == 0)
```

Why?

If `value` is 01110011

Then

```
01110011
&
00000100
--------
```

Will return 0 because 4th bit is off.

Comment: The equality operator has higher precedence than bitwise-and, and since `4 == 0` is `false`, which can be implicitly converted to zero, the bitwise-and always returns `false`. You must have parentheses thus `if ((value & 4) == 0)`

Answer (score 2):

the line from hastebin is poorly written, has unreachable code and depends heavily on the Precedence of the C operators. And doesn't work as expected.

The line from hastebin:

```
if( cur_w > source.xpos + source.width
&&
!(source.attributes & DBOX_HAS_SHADOW) )
{
    break;
    return; 
}
```

it should be written as:

```
if( (cur_w > (source.xpos + source.width))  // has curr_w exceeded sum of two other fields?
    &&
    ((source.attributes & DBOX_HAS_SHADOW) != DBOX_HAS_SHADOW ) //is bit == 0?
{
    break;
}
```

Comment: But it does, actually. The problem was based on an external conditional interfering. For that time I would do more then that, js.